# How to insert List<LocalDateTime> in room database?

Tags: gson, android-room, kotlinx-datetime

I am using LocalDateTime from kotlinx-datetime library. Want to insert `List<LocalDateTime>` in Room database. Typeconverter written using Gson library. But following error showing.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.time.LocalDate.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at java.time.LocalDateTime.toString(LocalDateTime.java:1966)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2924)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
                                                                                                        at com.quixcure.pillu.data.model.DoseTiming.toString(Unknown Source:27)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2924)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
                                                                                                        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2924)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.Assert.format(Assert.java:844)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
                                                                                                        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
```

Comment: Please include the code of your type adapter. Please also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).